# Axiomatizability of the multiplication of a ring

Tags: model-theory

The operation of ring multiplication is axiomatizable, if we allow ourselves an additional auxillary addition symbol. Just write down the ring axioms in the signature $\{*,+\}$. But could multiplication be axiomatizable by itself, without an auxillary aid?

That is to say, consider the class of structures $(R, *)$ such that there exists an operation $+$ that makes $(R, +, *)$ into a ring. Is that class axiomatizable in the signature $\{*\}$?

The more important question is, is there a standard term in the logic literature for a class of relations or operations which may not necessarily be axiomatizable by themselves, but can be so with the aid of auxillary relations and/or operations? I am sorry if my questions sound a little confusing at first.

Comment: To answer your second question, a class of $L$-structures $K$ is called a $\text{PC}_\Delta$-class (or a "pseudo-elementary class") if there is a language $L'\supseteq L$ and an $L'$-theory $T$ such that $K = \text{Mod}(T)|_L$, the class of reducts to $L$ of models of $T$. I believe this is the notion you're interested in. The notation $\text{PC}_\Delta$-class is unfortunate, but PC stands for "Pseudo-elementary Class", and the $\Delta$ denotes that the theory $T$ may be infinite. A $\text{PC}$-class (without the $\Delta$) is the class of reducts to $L$ of models of a single $L'$-sentence.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question to make it more readable. If my changes were too drastic, I apologize.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the previous version was very hard to read. In general, you should try to divide your posts into paragraphs (like Alex did). A wall of text is very discouraging.

Comment: That said, it's an interesting question. +1. :)

Comment: -1 This question looks interesting, but its not very clear, to me at least. I'm willing to remove my downvote if you're willing to rewrite the whole question.

Comment: I don't see why this question is considered unclear; even pre-edit, the sentence "That is to say, consider the class of structures $(R, *)$ where $*$ is an operation such that there exists an operation $+$ that makes $(R, +, *)$ into a ring. Is that class axiomatizable, with simply the signature $*$?" seems perfectly clear to me. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first Question: "That is to say, consider the class of structures $(R, *)$ such that there exists an operation $+$ that makes $(R, +, *)$ into a ring. Is that class axiomatizable in the signature $\{*\}$?"

The Answer: "No." This is proved in

Kogalovskiĭ, S. R.
The multiplicative semigroups of rings. (Russian)
Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 140 1961 1005–1007.